# Where do Docker containers COPY files inside a container?

Tags: docker

I've ssh'd inside a docker container to debug whether file(s) were copied correctly. I have no idea where the files are being copied inside the docker container from the `COPY` command in a `Dockerfile`. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Including your `COPY` command would help us help you. I suspect you are doing `COPY path1 path2 path3` thinking those are all local to the build context, but docker is interpreting `path3` as the destination within the container filesystem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last argument to `COPY` is the destination on the container filesystem. This could be an absolute path or a relative path, in which case it is relative to the `WORKDIR` setting in your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: I wasn't using `WORKDIR` - that cleared it up for me!